# How do I restore checkout: git restore --source=HEAD :/ using Source Tree or GitHub Desktop?

Tags: github, checkout, restore, atlassian-sourcetree, using

I am an artist. I have downloaded the repository and it did not check out. I had to pay for GitLFS. I have the project. I just need to restore the checkout connection. How do I do this in source tree? I am not a programmer. Wheres the button for this command? git restore --source=HEAD :/

Answer (score 0):

I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58657607/6309) SourceTree (and GitHub Desktop) has not yet integrated [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) (which remains an experimental command to replace the [confusing `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

With SourceTree, you can right-click on the origin/master and checkout a new branch

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39UoG.png]